# write regex for combination of caps and numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `ABC No.BC2345GFSD234CD`. I was trying to write a regex in python to extract `BC2345GFSD234CD`. I had a few more expressions which all depend on this. I tried something like `^[^\.]*\.(?P<number>[A-Z0-9]*).*$`. Is there some elegant way to do this?

EDIT: I have a file with many `regex`. There is another program that would pick up these regex and use `re.match`on some strings. It's a generic program and I need to fit in my regex as per it.  Also I need to use `re.match()` and not `re.search()`.

Some more strings could be:-

'< lot_of_spaces >ABC No.BC2345GFSD234CD< lot_of_spaces >'

'< lot_of_spaces >no-ABC.BC2345GFSD234CD< lot_of_spaces >'

In every case I need to extract- `BC2345GFSD234CD`

Comment: Well, there's a whole lot of complexity there that doesn't seem to be required by your description or your example, but presumably you wrote it for some reason you haven't shared with us, so it's hard to know what else you could write instead that would meet the requirements we don't know.

Comment: In particular: Why do you want to match start of line followed by 0 or more any-characters followed by 0 or more non-dot characters followed by a dot, instead of, say, a dot character? And why do you want to match 0 or more characters followed by end of line instead of just anything?

Comment: The regular expression you need is very depended on the data you have and how the instances differ. You only gave a rather short part of the text. and seeing your `.*$` raises the question if there is more.

Comment: Made an edit. Just trying to clarify  why I need this.

Comment: @KlausD. That won't matter. `re.match` would return me `number=BC2345GFSD234CD` even if I had a string like `ABC No.BC2345GFSD234CD asf.hghASD123`. I am interested in the 1st occurance only.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. I still don't understand why you think you need to match, say, 0 or more anything followed by 0 or more non-dots followed by a dot. Or why you used `*` instead of `+` on the alphanumeric class. If you can't explain it in regex or in English, maybe you can at least give us some examples that show why the obvious simple version doesn't work, and we can work out what you're trying to do from that. But with what we have, it's not possible to work out anything.

Comment: @BarunSharma always try to explain your problem at very first. Could you add the contents of regex file and the input file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yep just missed on it. Thanks..will try that.

Comment: Where is the regex file?

Comment: @abarnert Check the edit. Mostly I meant that I don't know the string(it's a variable). But the surety is that I will have a string with a combination of <caps> and <numbers>.

Comment: @AvinashRaj.. I have given an example of the regex `^.*[^\.]*\.(?P<number>[A-Z0-9]*).*$`. The file will have many such regex. And I have given few more string examples.

Comment: @BarunSharma try `\b[A-Z\d]*(?:\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d)[A-Z\d]*\b`

Comment: @abarnert .... well what the expression matches is :- get anything till I get a `.`. Then from `.`, get the sting with a combination of caps and nums(and assign the extracted part to variable `number`). And then skip everything beyond that. Hope that clears the regex in plain english.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76152/discussion-between-barun-sharma-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex.

```
>>> "ABC No.BC2345GFSD234CD".split('.')[-1]
'BC2345GFSD234CD'
```

**OR**

If you want really want to use regex then you may try this. This would match all non-dot characters exists at the last.

```
>>> re.search(r'[^.]*$', "ABC No.BC2345GFSD234CD").group()
'BC2345GFSD234CD'
```

Comment: I didn't explain in the question, but my program is something like---a file with a list of  `regex`. Another file picks up strings and `matches` the regex(not searches the regex).

Comment: @BarunSharma "I didn't explain in the question" - rephrase your question and include it, so we, and future users, can understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the last 15 characters you need, just slice the string:

```
>>> 'ABC No.BC2345GFSD234CD'[-15:]
'BC2345GFSD234CD'
```